# Three JS Shadow Opacity

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js, shadow

Hey all I've loaded a custom model in my canvas and everything worked fine. The only issue I get is that I have no glue how to get my shadow transparent on the model itself (the models should cast and receive a shadow).

my code looks like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('model/p3.json', handle_load);

    var mesh;
    function handle_load(geometry, materials) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);

        scene.add(mesh);
        mesh.position.z = 0;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.rotation.y = 5;


        //LIGHT
        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.15);
        ambient.target = mesh;

        scene.add(ambient);

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        light.target = mesh;
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.position.z = -150;
        light.position.y = 150;
        light.position.x = 150;
        light.shadow.bias = 0;
        light.shadowDarkness = 0.2;
        light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048 * 2;
        light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048 * 2;
        scene.add(light);
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        mesh.castShadow = true;

    }

    var shadowmaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
    shadowmaterial.opacity = 0.2;


    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
    });

    var geometry3 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500, 100, 100);
    var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, shadowmaterial);
    mesh3.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI / 180;
    mesh3.position.y = 0;
    scene.add(mesh3);

     mesh3.receiveShadow = true;
```

Rendering looks like this:

[image]

I appreciate every help

Comment: This example might help: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_hemisphere

Comment: @Radio Thanks for the tip! Can you explain how that would help?

Answer (score 0):

Because your mesh material is always gray and the floor white, there will always be a contrast in shadows . From my findings, shadows are intended to have this kind of physical realism built into them that dont allow much tweaking directly through some shadow property you tend to approach by adjust materials and lights.

You can drop your plane material color to a gray instead of a white and bump up your light intensity. Or brighten your mesh material and drop your light intensity.

You can also play with adding more lights and adjusting them. Upping the ambient light and reducing the directional should decrease shadow contrast.  Other kinds of lights will also have effects.

You can also play different aspects of the material to make whiter and darker thus effecting shadow. One example is reflectivity. So if you lowered directional but wanted it still react with the directional you might play with the reflectivity and specular.